# Customize textual representation of a Rails ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I configure the textual representation of a model (ActiveRecord object)?

Let's say I have a model `User`. In my form view, the code `f.submit` generate a submit button, with the text "Create User" or "Update User".
I would like to customize this text. I could write `f.submit "Create Awesome User"` and `f.submit "Update Awesome User"` depending of the action being performed, but I would expect Rails to offer a way to do this more easily, in a DRYer way.

More specifically, in my case, I have an ActiveRecord class `IosApplication`. In the forms, the submit button has the text : "*Update Ios application*", and I would like to see "*Update iOS  application*"

I looked into the ActiveRecord documentation, but the only thing related was `set_table_name`, which does not seem to be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for can be seen as localizing the app. So the, Internationalization part gave something nice enough:

Having this in my `config/locales/en.yml` worked:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      ios_application: iOS Application
```

More info on [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models).

I am not accepting this answer before a few days, in case a nicer answer is posted by someone with more experience in Rails.